# MongoDBODBC - Error from MongoDB Client: No servers yet eligible for rescan (Error Code: 13053)

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, polybase

I'm facing a problem with my PolyBase. I'm using my SQL Server to access data in MongoDB Atlas Database. However. when I try to create my external table I have the following error:

> 105082;Generic ODBC error: [Microsoft][MongoDBODBC] (110) Error from
> MongoDB Client: No servers yet eligible for rescan (Error Code: 13053)
> Additional error <2>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][MongoDBODBC] (110) Error
> from MongoDB Client: No servers yet eligible for rescan (Error Code:
> 13053), SqlState: HY000, NativeError: 110 .

At the moment, my script is :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE mongodb_test
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'mongodb://cls-data-dev-biconnector.a8m8q.mongodb.net:27015',
    CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'tls=false',
    CREDENTIAL = mongodb_test
)

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE base360 (
    [_id] VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    [ds_Contexto] varchar(max)  NULL
)
WITH (
    LOCATION='[db-data].[db-mng-ins-corporate-dev]',
    DATA_SOURCE= mongodb_test
);
```

What should I do? I didn't find a solution to solve this problem.
Can someone help me, please?

Thank you

Comment: What type of service are you using in GCP? Also, you can try checking the suggestions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/322245/polybase-feature-is-not-enabled.html).

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue? NB, the default port for Mongo is 27017, not 27015